# Orleans Observables vs Streams

Tags: orleans

**Which observers and streams work best for the following scenario:**

We have several consumers that receive messages from external services. Each consumer then processes the received message and then updates a grain state. The grain then notifies the clients of these changes. Grains notification fires and forget.
my question is to notify clients with make grain as an observable or to use streams?